# Make Visual Studio use a Windows 10 Mobile emulator installed on the other machine

Tags: visual-studio, hyper-v

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2015 to use 
the Windows 10 Mobile emulator installed on a remote Hyper-V server for debugging & testing UWP apps instead of having VS spin up the emulator VMs locally?

The server is a dedicated Hyper-V machine which has plenty of RAM and CPU power to run multiple emulator instances simultaneously. The machines are connected by a 1 Gbps Ethernet, and the PC's Hyper-V Manager is already set up to interact with the remote VMs on the server (i.e. create/start/shutdown/save etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible today.